# Delete/Create View Every Time Insert Is Done

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, view

Is it possible that each time a table has a record inserted, delete a view, then re-create a view using the data in the table.  For example, my table structure is like such

```
Create Table NeedView (
  Databasename varchar(100)
  ,DateAdded datetime
)
```

And the information in that table is just a fully qualified database name like so `servername.database.dbo.table`  My thought is to have a trigger applied that each time a record is inserted into this table, 1st drop the view (it would be called `dbo.ViewMaster` then recreate it with a quick `select` of

```
Select fullname, phone
```

from each table in the database.  Is this achievable through a trigger?

EDIT

I now just need to figure out how to cycle the table to create a view for each databasename in the table...I have this rough syntax ready, with the exception of actually iterating each database.  Can someone help me with the missing piece?

```
CREATE TRIGGER GetViewReady ON [FullOn]
FOR INSERT
AS
  IF OBJECT_ID('FullInformation', 'V') IS NOT NULL
  DROP VIEW FullInformation

  Declare @database varchar(100), @campaignID varchar(10)

  Declare C1 Cursor FOR

    Select database
    FROM [FullOn]

  Open C1

  Fetch Next FROM C1 INTO @database

  WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
  Begin

    'Here is where the actual iteration to create the view would go...
    'How would that statement actually need to be syntactically written?

    Fetch Next From C1 Into @database

End


GO
```

EDIT --
A few database names would be `hellfire.master.dbo.hennigar`, `hellfire.mainframe.dbo.dekalb`, `hellfire.master.dbo.ftworth` and the syntax I am after would be like so:

```
Select fullname, phone
FROM hellfire.master.dbo.hennigar
UNION ALL
select fullname, phone
from hellfire.mainframe.dbo.dekalb
UNION ALL
select fullname, phone
from hellfire.master.dbo.ftworth
```

Comment: This seems like a weird solution (to a problem that hasn't been fully explained).  Nonetheless, if it is a viable solution, would you post a sample definition of the view with a few of the db names?

Comment: So your database names (master, mainframe, etc) will be stored in table `NeedView`, right?  What about the table names (hennigar, dekalb, ftworth, etc.)?

Comment: The fully qualified names...I get that.  But I still don't see where you're getting the schema names (dbo) and table names (hennigar, dekalb, ftworth, etc.) from.  Am I missing something?  Is the fully qualified name stored in column `DatabaseName` in your table `NeedView`?

Comment: Ah, I see.  They are manually being input into the table.  It's essentially a list of tablenames that already exist on the server, but need this "special" view created for them.